# Why does SingleChildScrollView center an Horizontal Row, when it isn't supposed to?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, singlechildscrollview

I have this code:

```dart
  Widget _buildPaymentMethodList() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Row(
        children: paymentMethods.map((paymentMethod) => _buildPaymentMethodItem(paymentMethod)).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

and the `SingleChildScrollView` in the layout centers the child `Row` that should be scrolled horizontally

But when I remove the `SingleChildScrollView`, the `Row` aligns to the left:

```dart
  Widget _buildPaymentMethodList() {
    return Row(
      children: paymentMethods.map((paymentMethod) => _buildPaymentMethodItem(paymentMethod)).toList(),
    );
  }
```

It's weird, and I don't know what is forcing the `SingleChildScrollView` to center the `Row` when I didn't event use a `Center` widget

I even tried looking a the  `_buildPaymentMethodItem` method, but couldn't figure it out

**Edit:**

**Without the custom widget:**

```
Widget _buildPaymentMethodItem(String paymentMethod) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Checkbox(
            value: selectedItem == paymentMethod,
            onChanged: (_) {
              setState(() {
                selectedItem = paymentMethod;
              });
            },
          ),
          Text(
            paymentMethod,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

**Edit:**

**With the custom widget (that produces the same UI as the picture)**

```dart
  Widget _buildPaymentMethodItem(String paymentMethod) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(Dimensions.space1),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: AppColor.white,
        border: WidgetUtil.borderPrimaryTint,
        borderRadius: WidgetUtil.borderRadiusRoundedAllSides,
      ),
      child: AppCheckBox(
        checked: selectedItem == paymentMethod,
        size: 16,
        text: paymentMethod,
        onChanged: (_) {
          setState(() {
            selectedItem = paymentMethod;
          });
        },
      ),
    ).paddingRight(Dimensions.space1);
  }
```

I got something like this:

[image: centered]

But I expect something like this:

[image: left]

**Full Code**

```
class PaymentMethodRadio extends StatefulWidget {
  const PaymentMethodRadio({super.key});

  @override
  State<PaymentMethodRadio> createState() => _PaymentMethodRadioState();
}

class _PaymentMethodRadioState extends State<PaymentMethodRadio> {
  late String selectedItem;
  final List<String> paymentMethods = ['Card', 'Cash', 'Paystack'];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedItem = paymentMethods[0];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text('Payment method'),
        const SizedBox(height: Dimensions.space1),
        _buildPaymentMethodList(),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPaymentMethodList() {
    return Row(
      children: paymentMethods.map((paymentMethod) => _buildPaymentMethodItem(paymentMethod)).toList(),
    );
  }

      Widget _buildPaymentMethodItem(String paymentMethod) {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          ),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Checkbox(
                value: selectedItem == paymentMethod,
                onChanged: (_) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedItem = paymentMethod;
                  });
                },
              ),
              Text(
                paymentMethod,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
```

Comment: There are many custom widgets on your post which is unknown from our end, It would be nice to simplify the snippet in one so that everyone can understand.

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh Okay, I added an alternate code to reproduce the error

Comment: somehow I am getting the expected result from your snippet, can you include full sample widget from scaffold body that will reproduce the same error?

Comment: You could resize the screen to see the overflow. But I have now added the full code

Comment: Thanks for adding full snippet, can check out [this code](https://pastebin.com/BPRtbAgB)

Comment: You basically just gave me back the same code as I wrote. On larger screens, the SingleChildScrollView centers the rows still.

Comment: add `mainAxisSize` in your `Row`, set it to "min"

Comment: @pskink, I just tried that now, but it still gave the same issue. I haven't run the code on mobile, I am using chrome to test

Comment: @pskink nothing is in code

Answer (score 0):

I tried your full code with a little edit (add SingleChildScrollView and sizing). I don't face any issues in this code. Heres my result:

[image: Result]

And this is the full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'John',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const PaymentMethodRadio(),
    );
  }
}

class PaymentMethodRadio extends StatefulWidget {
  const PaymentMethodRadio({super.key});

  @override
  State<PaymentMethodRadio> createState() => _PaymentMethodRadioState();
}

class _PaymentMethodRadioState extends State<PaymentMethodRadio> {
  late String selectedItem;
  final List<String> paymentMethods = ['Card', 'Cash', 'Paystack'];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedItem = paymentMethods[0];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const Text('Payment method'),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            _buildPaymentMethodList(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPaymentMethodList() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Row(
        children: paymentMethods
            .map((paymentMethod) => _buildPaymentMethodItem(paymentMethod))
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPaymentMethodItem(String paymentMethod) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Checkbox(
              value: selectedItem == paymentMethod,
              onChanged: (_) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedItem = paymentMethod;
                });
              },
            ),
            Text(
              paymentMethod,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Im using flutter:

```
Flutter 3.13.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision ff5b5b5fa6 (6 weeks ago) • 2023-08-24 08:12:28 -0500
Engine • revision b20183e040
Tools • Dart 3.1.0 • DevTools 2.25.0
```

If you still have the issue, try to add `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start` in your `_buildPaymentMethodList()`

Comment: As I stated in the question, I tried this already

Comment: Did you try my code and still got that issue? if so, i don't get it if the same code produce different result

Comment: hey checkout @pskink comment try it i guess that the answer!

Comment: Go through my code once more., I already stated there that I had already tried it, and I am using the latest version of Flutter too